# getting maximum and minimum after inputting 4 real numbers for java

Tags: java, max, min

here is what i have so far. i had to get the avg of 4 real numbers then get the maximum and minimum. i was able to get

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AverageMaxMin {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

                System.out.println("Enter 4 numbers:");
                Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in); 

                    double a,b,c,d;

                    double avg;

                    a=input.nextDouble();
                    b=input.nextDouble();
                    c=input.nextDouble();
                    d=input.nextDouble();
                    avg=(double)(a+b+c+d)/4.0;
                    System.out.println("The Average is: " + avg);

    }
}
```

Comment: I would look into, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max(double,%20double) the method below deals with getting the minimum.

Comment: @pshemo sorry for the shouting.

Comment: @MattBrzezinski thanks. ill look into it right now

Comment: To get the max you can just do `Math.max(Math.max(a, b), Math.max(c, d));`, to find the minimum you can do similar just replace with the appropriate method. @zeogold

Comment: @MattBrzezinski oh okay. this is how i was doing it                                                 "if( a > b ){
           double max1 = a;
           double max2 = b;

Comment: That works as well, there are many ways of doing this, just doing a greater than / less than comparison works just as well.

I only suggested the Math library because you can one line like so,

`System.out.println("Max = " + Math.max(Math.max(a, b), Math.max(c, d)) + "\nMin = " + Math.min(Math.min(a, b), Math.min(c, d)));`

EDIT: It would be best to do like @Mike Jenkins suggested with iterating, you can add in the values into an array and then loop through to find the maximum and minimum. This would be best because it allows you to expand easily.

Comment: @MattBrzezinski thanksill give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Try looping over the numbers and track the lowest and highest numbers seen.